# Issues with Zsh prompt

Tags: zsh, oh-my-zsh

My Zsh prompt cursor is sometimes (most of the time actually) a line below were it should be (attaching screenshot):

[image]

If I hit enter multiple times, the prompt seems to get fixed:

[image]

My first thought is that it was an error within my custom prompt, so I replaced by prompt with a simple one containing only one digit:

```
PROMPT='> '
```

But the error persisted.

Any clues about what can be missing?

You can find my theme here: http://pastebin.com/cSJwGWKZ.

Notice that I'm using Oh My Zsh.

**EDIT:** The prompt seems to get fixed when I reach the bottom of the terminal (by hitting enters).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The culprit is `%{$(echotc DO 1)%}` in your `RPROMPT`, which moves the cursor one line down when printing `RPROMPT`. When reaching the bottom of your terminal there is no additional line to go down to, so the cursor just remains where it was.

Depending on where you want your `RPROMPT` you have basically two options:

- On the same line as your input cursor (after `λ`):
  Just remove `%{$(echotc DO 1)%}` from your `RPROMPT`:

```
RPROMPT='$(_git_time_since_commit) $(git_prompt_status) ${_return_status}%'
```

- One line (or any other number of lines, really) above your input:
  Add `%{$(echotc UP 1)%}` at the beginning of your `RPROMPT`, this will move the cursor up one line, print the right prompt and move back down one line:

```
RPROMPT='%{$(echotc UP 1)%}$(_git_time_since_commit) $(git_prompt_status) ${_return_status}%{$(echotc DO 1)%}'`
```

---

Note: the second method may lead to `RPROMPT` overwriting parts of `PROMPT` if both get to long and/or the terminal window to narrow. If `RPROMPT` remains on the same line as input, it will be hidden once the input reaches it (and will reapper if you delete some of the input).